# I see JSessionIds that don't belong to my webapp

Tags: java, spring-security, tomcat7, jsessionid, session-hijacking

I'm running a website on my own VPS and static IP. The website is a Java/Spring(MVC,Security) based application and runs inside tomcat 7 container.

When I go to the tomcat manager page, I see over 300 session that are active and none of looks normal to me. All session the have on attribute:

```
SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST =DefaultSavedRequest[http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=RkQo8hVGcC8&el=info&hl=en_US&asv=3&sts=16806&eurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DRkQo8hVGcC8]
```

A normal session to my site has a different value to the above attribute

```
SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST=DefaultSavedRequest[http://PATH TO MY SITE]
```

- Are my site sessions being hacked by bot?
- How is it possible for outsider to create a session on my own  tomcat container?

I just want to know what I'm up against in this situation, so I can deal with it properly. Your help is appreciated.